# Using wordpress:php8.3-fpm-alpine and nginx:stable-alpine as base image for wordPress applications

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, docker, nginx

I am trying to migrate my Docker image which uses `library/wordpress:php8.2-apache` as base image to `library/wordpress:php8.3-fpm-alpine` and `nginx:stable-alpine` as base images.
Here is my Dockerfile

```
# Stage 1: Build the WordPress application
FROM library/wordpress:php8.3-fpm-alpine AS build

# Install wp-cli
RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar && \
    chmod +x wp-cli.phar && \
    mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

# Use different mirrors
RUN sed -i -e 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/g' /etc/apk/repositories

# Install Postfix
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache postfix && \
    postconf -e myhostname=mydomain.com && \
    postconf -e relayhost="mailfwd.mydomain.com" && \
    postfix start && \
    postfix reload

# Configure PHP and create directory if it doesn't exist
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
    echo "sendmail_path=sendmail -t -i" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sendmail.ini

# Install packages: wget, bash
RUN apk add --no-cache wget bash

# Install net-tools
RUN apk add --no-cache net-tools

# Copy built files to WordPress files system
COPY default/ /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/default/

# Set permissions for the wp-install-plugins.sh script
COPY wp-install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wp-install-plugins.sh

# Grant permissions to the www-data user
RUN chown www-data:www-data /usr/local/bin/wp-install-plugins.sh


# Stage 2: Build the NGINX server
FROM nginx:stable-alpine AS nginx-server

# Copy the NGINX configuration
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy static content from WordPress build stage
COPY --from=build /var/www/html/wp-content /var/www/html/wp-content

# Expose port 80 to allow incoming connections
EXPOSE 80

# Command to start NGINX when the container starts
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My nginx.conf file is:

```
server {
  listen 80;   # Listen on IPv4 address only
  access_log off;
  root /var/www/html;

  index index.php;
  server_tokens off;
  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on wordpress:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

I am able to successfully build the image and run the container, but the container just errors out with the following

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: ipv6 not available
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.24.0
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.1 20220924 (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4)
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.0-92-generic
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 20
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 21
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 22
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
2024/02/26 20:23:08 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 27
2024/02/26 20:26:01 [error] 20#20: *1 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden
```

When I try to exec into the container, it just says

```
docker exec -it my_container bash
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Even though, I did install bash in the Dockerfile. May I please what I am doing wrong and how can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Your `Dockerfile` has two `FROM` sections. You install `bash` before the second `FROM` but don't explicitly copy the installed files into your image.

Perhaps it is worth refactoring your `Dockerfile` to call `apk` after the second `FROM` for packages needed in the final image.

To demonstrate that this is the problem, here's your original `Dockerfile` modified to reinstall `bash` after the second `FROM` which works around the problem:

```
# Stage 1: Build the WordPress application
FROM library/wordpress:php8.3-fpm-alpine AS build

# Install wp-cli
RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar && \
    chmod +x wp-cli.phar && \
    mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

# Use different mirrors
RUN sed -i -e 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/g' /etc/apk/repositories

# Install Postfix
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache postfix && \
    postconf -e myhostname=mydomain.com && \
    postconf -e relayhost="mailfwd.mydomain.com" && \
    postfix start && \
    postfix reload

# Configure PHP and create directory if it doesn't exist
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
    echo "sendmail_path=sendmail -t -i" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sendmail.ini

# Install packages: wget, bash
RUN apk add --no-cache wget bash

# Install net-tools
RUN apk add --no-cache net-tools

# Copy built files to WordPress files system
COPY default/ /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/default/

# Set permissions for the wp-install-plugins.sh script
COPY wp-install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wp-install-plugins.sh

# Grant permissions to the www-data user
RUN chown www-data:www-data /usr/local/bin/wp-install-plugins.sh


# Stage 2: Build the NGINX server
FROM nginx:stable-alpine AS nginx-server

# Copy the NGINX configuration
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy static content from WordPress build stage
COPY --from=build /var/www/html/wp-content /var/www/html/wp-content

# Install bash in current image
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash

# Expose port 80 to allow incoming connections
EXPOSE 80

# Command to start NGINX when the container starts
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: This worked, but I am still seeing errors in the container that I mentioned above. Any help?

Comment: @merilstack perhaps open a new question using an updated Dockerfile and the current error you are receiving? The answer I gave probably only addresses the missing `bash` part of your original problem.

Comment: @merilstack looks like the remaining problem is similar - the image resulting from the 2nd `FROM` is missing some things - e.g. there's no user `www-data`, postfix is not installed, etc. You can use `docker exec -it my_container bash` to debug further.

Comment: when I check the logs
`docker logs -f my_container` It says the following:
`2024/02/28 22:31:24 [error] 26#26: *400 directory index of "/var/www/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.18.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "myapp.domain.com"`
`2024/02/28 14:26:56 [error] 20#20: *291 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.2, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.20:9000", host: ""myapp.domain.com", referrer: "https://"myapp.domain.com/"`

Comment: And When I do `docker exec -it my_container bash` and check the contents `my_container:/# ls` `bash: /bin/ls: Permission denied`

Comment: Is there anything that I am doing wrong in the Dockerfile @davejagoda?

Comment: I have posted a new question here for the issues @davejagoda: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78078693/migrating-from-wordpressphp8-2-apache-to-wordpressphp8-3-fpm-alpine-and-nginx