# Migrating from wordpress:php8.2-apache to wordpress:php8.3-fpm-alpine and nginx:stable-alpine as base image for wordpress applications

Tags: php, wordpress, bash, docker, nginx

I am trying to migrate my Docker image which uses library/wordpress:php8.2-apache as base image to library/wordpress:php8.3-fpm-alpine and nginx:stable-alpine as base images. Here is my Dockerfile

```
# Stage 1: Build the WordPress application
FROM library/wordpress:php8.3-fpm-alpine AS build

# Install wp-cli
RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar && \
    chmod +x wp-cli.phar && \
    mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

# Use different mirrors
RUN sed -i -e 's/dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/mirrors.aliyun.com/g' /etc/apk/repositories

# Install Postfix
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache postfix && \
    postconf -e myhostname=mydomain.com && \
    postconf -e relayhost="mailfwd.mydomain.com" && \
    postfix start && \
    postfix reload

# Configure PHP and create directory if it doesn't exist
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/ && \
    echo "sendmail_path=sendmail -t -i" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/sendmail.ini

# Install packages: wget, bash
RUN apk add --no-cache wget bash

# Install net-tools
RUN apk add --no-cache net-tools

# Copy built files to WordPress files system
COPY default/ /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/default/

# Set permissions for the wp-install-plugins.sh script
COPY wp-install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wp-install-plugins.sh

# Grant permissions to the www-data user
RUN chown www-data:www-data /usr/local/bin/wp-install-plugins.sh


# Stage 2: Build the NGINX server
FROM nginx:stable-alpine AS nginx-server

# Install bash in current image
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash

# Check if www-data group exists, if not, add it
RUN if ! getent group www-data >/dev/null; then addgroup -g 1000 www-data; fi

# Add www-data user with existing www-data group
RUN adduser -D -H -u 1000 -G www-data -s /bin/bash www-data

# Copy the NGINX configuration
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy default index.php file
COPY default/index.php /var/www/html/

# Copy static content from WordPress build stage
COPY --from=build --chown=www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content /var/www/html/wp-content

# Set permissions for static content
RUN find /var/www/html/wp-content -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && \
    find /var/www/html/wp-content -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

# Expose port 80 to allow incoming connections
EXPOSE 80

# Command to start NGINX when the container starts
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My nginx.conf file is:

```
server {
  listen 80;   # Listen on IPv4 address only
  access_log off;
  root /var/www/html;

  index index.php;
  server_tokens off;
  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }
  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on wordpress:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

I am able to successfully build the image and run the container and the container is healthy as well,but for some reason when I go inside the container and run any command it just shows `permission denied`

```
docker exec -it my_container bash
my_container:/# ls -l
bash: /bin/ls: Permission denied
```

I also see the following error when I check the logs of my container by `docker logs -f my_container` while trying to hit the url of my application

```
2024/02/29 03:06:59 [error] 21#21: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.13:9000", host: "myapp.mydomain.com"
2024/02/29 03:06:59 [warn] 21#21: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.13:9000", host: "myapp.mydomain.com"
```

Is there anything wrong with my Dockerfile and the configuration? May I please know what I am doing wrong or missing so that I can fix these issues?

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be a few components missing from your question. The problem seems to be, however, with NGINX being unable to find the service at `wordpress:9000`.

This is a working setup which should at least get you started.

```
├── default
│   └── index.php
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── nginx.conf
└── wp-install-plugins.sh
```

`Dockerfile` (I have stripped out the stuff relating to `postfix` and `sendmail` because it's unclear what role they play in your project and don't seem to be germane to the problem anyway.)

```
# STAGE 1: WORDPRESS --------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM library/wordpress:php8.3-fpm-alpine AS build

RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar && \
    chmod +x wp-cli.phar && \
    mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

RUN apk add --no-cache wget bash net-tools

COPY default/ /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/default/
COPY wp-install-plugins.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wp-install-plugins.sh && \
    chown www-data:www-data /usr/local/bin/wp-install-plugins.sh

# STAGE 2: NGINX ------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM nginx:stable-alpine AS nginx-server

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache bash

RUN if ! getent group www-data >/dev/null; then addgroup -g 1000 www-data; fi

RUN adduser -D -H -u 1000 -G www-data -s /bin/bash www-data

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY default/index.php /var/www/html/

COPY --from=build --chown=www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content /var/www/html/wp-content

RUN find /var/www/html/wp-content -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; && \
    find /var/www/html/wp-content -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`docker-compose.yml` (This uses the `Dockerfile` above to build images for both the `wordpress` and `nginx` services.)

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  wordpress:
    container_name: wordpress
    build:
      context: .
      target: build
    volumes:
      - wordpress-data:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: .
      target: nginx-server
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress-data:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
    networks:
      - app-network

volumes:
  wordpress-data:
  db-data:

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

`nginx.conf` is the same as provided in question.

Build and run.

```
docker-compose up --build
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @datawookie, the issue is I am not using the docker-compose to build the image. But I am using it to do the deployment. I have added the docker-compose in the answer. Would you recommend any modification in that setup?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is I am not using the docker-compose to build the image. But I am using it to do the deployment. It is as follows:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: registry.io:5000/wp-image:current
    container_name: wordpress_1
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
    restart: always
    hostname: my-wp-app.mydomain.io
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: WP_HOST
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: WP_DB_USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: WP_DB_PWD
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: WP_DB_NAME
      VIRTUAL_HOST: my-wp-app.mydomain.io
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 80
    volumes:
      - /home/deploy/jenkins/my-wp-app/uploads:/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads
      - ${WORKSPACE}/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    external:
      name: reverse-proxy
```

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy for this wp-apps and also other apps running in the same server. Would you please recommend any modifications to the above answer to favor this setup?

Comment: You are referencing `registry.io:5000/wp-image:current`. Was that image built with the `Dockerfile` you provide in the question?

Comment: Yes, I used the Dockerfile and ngix.conf that you provided to build the image using the command `docker build "registry.io:5000/wp-image:current" --build-arg SOURCE_FOLDER="current" --no-cache ./`

Comment: I think you might need a `-t` after `build` in that command?

Comment: Yes, but how can I do the deployment with the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: @datawookie, I am able to do a build successfully using the command `docker build -t "registry.io:5000/wp-image:current" --build-arg SOURCE_FOLDER="current" --no-cache ./`. And it bundles app everything into a one image `current`. I tried doing the deployment with the docker-compose.yml as above and the container runs but when I check the logs it shows `2024/03/06 02:11:43 [error] 26#26: *4357 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.2, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.18.0.10:9000"`